# What's the controllers responsibility to give the view data in a certain format?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I've a controller that needs to return information to a View via Ajax + Json...fairly standard so far. But the component displaying the data requires it to be delivered in a very specific structure.

I'm loathed to start spitting back data to the view in such a specific manor in case I need to swap out that component later. It would mean changes to the controller and the view, not just the view.

Would it be a better idea to translate the data the controller is sending the view on the client side? Or am I being to anal about the seperation between view and controller, and should just bite the bullet and do it all in the controller?

Thanks,
Kieron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do these kind of conversions in the ViewModel class. I assume you are using ViewModel binding rather than direct Domain object binding in the strongly typed Views. I think that's exactly what ViewModel classes are for.

Then you can always the have converter functions inside those ViewModel and call them in the view.

Comment: I am indeed, I suppose that's completely right. I was trying to minimize the impact of a change to the view, but making it much more complex than it needed to be. If the GUI needs to change, then I'll have to update the code to reflect that....